# 404 when writing URL directly in browser to defined router route

Tags: angular

I have an app with a dashboard and from there you can go to some different pages inside the app. I need to access from another app to a URL defined in the router route of the first app, but I get a 404 not found. It also happens if I try write the URL directly in the browser.

Writing URL directly in browser to defined router route works in my computer but not in our production environment.

Comment: how about base href? wrong server config? melting of ice caps? full moon?

Comment: What WebServer are you using to serve the application? When your WebServer handles the request for a route defined with the routeProvide it may be that he tries to resolve the path and won't find it. You may need to redirect /* to the appropriate file. You should provide a minimal example that will reproduce this error if set up like your prod env.